# Array of array of string in c with malloc

Tags: c, linux, gcc

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong here ? I don't get the text when I print `printf("%s\n",text[0]);`

I created `char **text;` and `malloc`ed all pointers.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


char **text;

int main()
{
    int i; 
    text = malloc(20000);


    for(i=0; i < 20000; i++) {
        text[i] = malloc(4);

        memcpy(text[i], "test",4);
    }
    printf("%s\n",text[0]);
    printf("%s\n",text[1]);
}
```

Comment: Your strings are not null-terminated.

Comment: Also, malloc(20000) allocates 20000 *bytes*, and you're then trying to fill it with 20000 character pointers (which take several bytes each, and are overwriting each other).

Comment: Yeah, I should have done this  text = malloc(20000 * sizeof(char *));

Comment: And nick is also right...you need to allocate 5 bytes for the string "text" to accommodate the null terminator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking for something like this:

```
int numElements = 20000, i;
// Allocate an array of char pointers
text = malloc(numElements * sizeof( char *)); 

for( i = 0; i < numElements; i++) {
    // 4 for the length of the string "test", plus one additional for \0 (NULL byte)
    text[i] = malloc( (4 + 1) * sizeof( char));
    memcpy( text[i], "test\0", 5);
}
```

Here is an [online demo](http://ideone.com/n6xKrS) showing it working, as it produces the output:

```
test
test
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(i=0; i < 20000/sizeof(char*); i++) {
    text[i] = malloc(5);
    memcpy(text[i], "test",5);

}
```

Comment: Or, of course, change the first `malloc(20000)` to `malloc(20000 * sizeof(char *))`.